# UnsupportedOperationException: Alert dialogcrashing when positive button clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

So i have this recycler view in which the last item is supposed to show a dialog on its click. the dialog is further comprising of 2 buttons, positive and negetive( the default ones).
On the press of Positive button, the dialog is supposed to trigger a callback which will add a new entry in the recycler view. On the press of the negetive button, the dialog simply dismisses.

Everything is working fine until when the user clicks positive button. the app crashes with the following log:

```
2019-08-13 18:27:35.668 29482-29482/z.y.x E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: z.y.x, PID: 29482
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
        at z.y.x.dashboard_files.dashboard_fragment.QuantityButtonsAdapter.addItemInCentre(QuantityButtonsAdapter.java:85)
        at z.y.x.dashboard_files.dashboard_fragment.DashboardFragment$2$1.onPositiveButtonClick(DashboardFragment.java:144)
        at z.y.x.dashboard_files.dashboard_fragment.DashboardFragment$QuantityDialog$3.onClick(DashboardFragment.java:253)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:172)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Here is the custom dialog class:

```java
    public static class QuantityDialog {
        @Nullable
        private QuantityButtonModel currentData;
        private AlertDialog.Builder builder;

        public interface OnPositiveClickListener {
            void onPositiveButtonClick(QuantityButtonModel data);
        }

        public QuantityDialog(Context ctx) {
            currentData = QUANTITY_GLASS;
            View dialogView = createView(ctx);
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx)
                    .setView(dialogView)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
        }
//        public void show() {
//            show(null);
//        }

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        private View createView(Context ctx) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(ctx)
                    .inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_quantitiy_btn, null);

            //init ui
            SeekBar seekQty = v.findViewById(R.id.seekbar_qty);
            final TextView tvQty = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_qty_text_dialog);
            final ImageView ivQty = v.findViewById(R.id.iv_qty_icon_dialog);

            //init data and defaults
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                seekQty.setMin(0);
            }
            seekQty.setMax(QUANTITY_MAX);
            if (currentData != null) {
                seekQty.setProgress(currentData.getQty());
                tvQty.setText(String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%d ml", currentData.getQty()));
                ivQty.setImageResource(currentData.getQtyImage());
            }
            //init listener
            seekQty.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
                    tvQty.setText(String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%d ml", progress));
                    int resID = getResForQty(progress);
                    ivQty.setImageResource(resID);
                    currentData = new QuantityButtonModel(resID, progress);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }
            });

            return v;
        }

        public void setOnPositiveClickListener(@Nullable final OnPositiveClickListener listener) {
            builder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onPositiveButtonClick(currentData);
                    }
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }

        public void show() {
            builder.show();
        }

    }
```

Here I am setting a listener to my recycler view's adapter. the listener is made in a way that if item is at any positon except last, it will show a toast, else it will show a dialog. The dialog is also not being reused(bad naming, i changed it later), but rather getting generated on every click and a click listener being attached at the same point, i.e on rv item's click.

```java
        adpButtons.setClickListener(new QuantityButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int qty) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        fragView.getContext(),
                        "add:" + qty + " to shared preferences",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAddNewItemClick() {
                QuantityDialog reusableQuantityDialog;
                reusableQuantityDialog = new QuantityDialog(fragView.getContext());
                reusableQuantityDialog.setOnPositiveClickListener(
                        new OnPositiveClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPositiveButtonClick(QuantityButtonModel data) {
                                adpButtons.addItemInCentre(data);
                            }
                        });
                reusableQuantityDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

I hope i tried to explain this clearly. I am guessing there is some kind of callback hell that is causing the problem. But i even tried reusing the dialogs which still caused the same error.
Please help.

**Edit**: Here is the adapter code:

```java
public class QuantityButtonsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuantityButtonsAdapter.RvHolder> {


    @NonNull
    private List<QuantityButtonModel> buttonModelList;
    private QuantityButtonClickListener clickListener;

    QuantityButtonsAdapter() {
        this(new ArrayList<QuantityButtonModel>(), null);
    }

    private QuantityButtonsAdapter(@NonNull List<QuantityButtonModel> buttonModelList,
                                   QuantityButtonClickListener listener) {
        this.buttonModelList = buttonModelList;
        this.clickListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RvHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_recycler_buttons, parent, false);
        return new RvHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RvHolder holder, int pos) {
        QuantityButtonModel data = buttonModelList.get(pos);

        //is last is a check based on which our code to add new data will get triggerred
        boolean isLast = (pos==(buttonModelList.size()-1));
        holder.bind(data.getQtyImage(), data.getQty(), clickListener, isLast);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return buttonModelList.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    public List<QuantityButtonModel> getButtonModelList() {
        return buttonModelList;
    }

    public void setButtonModelList(@NonNull List<QuantityButtonModel> buttonModelList) {
        this.buttonModelList = buttonModelList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public QuantityButtonClickListener getClickListener() {
        return clickListener;
    }

    public void setClickListener(QuantityButtonClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void addItemInCentre(QuantityButtonModel model) {
        //int pos= buttonModelList.size()/2;
        buttonModelList.add(model);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class RvHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageButton ibtQty;
        TextView tvQty;

        RvHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ibtQty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibt_qty_btn);
            tvQty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_qty_text);
            //ibtQty.setOnTouchListener(getMyItemTouchListener());

        }

        void bind(int qtyRes, final int qty, final QuantityButtonClickListener listener, final boolean isLast) {

            ibtQty.setImageResource(qtyRes);
            tvQty.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d ml", qty));
            ibtQty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (isLast) {
                        listener.onAddNewItemClick();
                    } else {
                        listener.onItemClick(qty);
                    }

                    showButtonPressAnimation(view);

                }
            });
        }

    }


    interface QuantityButtonClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int qty);

        void onAddNewItemClick();
    }

    public static void showButtonPressAnimation(View view) {
        final float shrinkTo = 0.90f;
        final long duration = 100;
        ScaleAnimation grow = new ScaleAnimation(
                shrinkTo, 1,
                shrinkTo, 1,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

        grow.setDuration(duration / 2);


        ScaleAnimation shrink = new ScaleAnimation(
                1, shrinkTo,
                1, shrinkTo,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        shrink.setDuration(duration / 2);

        grow.setStartOffset(duration / 2);
        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
        set.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        set.addAnimation(shrink);
        set.addAnimation(grow);
        view.startAnimation(set);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't read through your Dialog source too much, but I don't expect any issue with it.

I guess the issue is `adpButtons.addItemInCentre(data);`, which you don't show in the question, but the `addItemInCentre` implementation is calling `List.add` on some list instance which is missing the `add` implementation.

Maybe it's some deserialized list, or some immutable one, can't recall from head any example, but I think there's some which can be created from Strings in XML, etc...

To have `add` available, you need list instance similar to `ArrayList`, etc...

So without showing this part of source, how the list (you try to `add` to) is defined and instantiated, it's difficult to tell precisely, what is the issue.

**Edit**: it's not clear from OP responses what precisely helped, but among the ways already mentioned above (deserialization, reflection), one can get the `List<>` instance with fixed size also by using the `Arrays.asList(..)` utility, which does NOT produce `ArrayList`, but specialized implementation of `List<>` which does bridge the original array with `List<>` interface (you can modify the original array through `List<>.set(index, value)` call), and thus it does refuse to do `add/remove` like operations, because underlying classic `Type[]` array is fixed size and the `add/remove` then would require new array, invalidating the original reference = makes no sense for `asList` functionality.

I.e. if you need implementation of [`java.util.List<E>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) interface which supports also `add` and `remove` like functionality of `List`, you must make sure the instance of your `List<>` is provided by class capable of these operations, like [`java.util.ArrayList<E>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [`java.util.Vector<E>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Vector.html), and avoid other implementations which do not support add/remove (like the one produced by `Arrays.asList(..)` call).

Also if you are writing Adapter, where you know you will need add/remove features of `List<>`, you may sometimes want to enforce particular `List` implementation, like `ArrayList`, on the API level, so when you later try to use that adapter with other implementation, it will fail at compile time. (then again having such specific API also prevents usage of other implementations which do support add/remove, and unfortunately the `List<E>` interface doesn't have direct interface derivative, which would ensure the add/remove are mandatory (they are optional in original `List<E>` interface), and could be used to narrow the API like that.

Comment: nope i am using the ArrayList only( well technically `List`, but initialising it /passing ArrayList<> of data in it at all places). Checkout the edit, i added the code for adapter. this method was supposed to add the button in the center, but i replaced that line of code with adding it to the end once the error started to come.

Comment: I don't see any `ArrayList` in the new part... I see you are doing `add` on the `private List<QuantityButtonModel> buttonModelList`, and you don't show code which is setting this up (either through constructor of the adapter, or through setButtonModelList ... if you are 100% sure you want to use this adapter only with ArrayList, you can actually change the `List<QuantityButtonModel>` type to `ArrayList<QuantityButtonModel>`, then the compiler will probably show you where you are setting it up with something different (unless you are using some very convoluted way of instancing it).

Comment: @anshsachdeva And from the VERY quick glance, I don't see anything particularly wrong about your code, it pretty much should work like that, i.e. I still believe your crash is because the list instance you have in adapter is not `ArrayList`, but some other `List` implementation, like 90% sure about it. (just put a breakpoint there, and see in debugger, what does it think about that particular instance, maybe it will provide some hint, what you have there)  (BTW, aren't you deserializing the list from Intent extras or shared preferences, or something like that?)

Comment: Okay am out of home, but will post the adapter setting up code too, in about an hour. And i think i can replace all the instances  of `List` with `ArrayList` .  Its just that with using livedata<list> many times, i had this habbit of using list everywhere. And i  never had a similar problem of using `add` ever. .. By the way, does Android have multiple classes with name List? I can't verify it now, but maybe the import might have caused error

Comment: @anshsachdeva https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html -> check the known subclasses ... (seems to me a bit too short, I think there are few more implementing the `List<..>` interface, maybe go also through `AbstractList` docs... Unless you see in debugger that your list is 100% `ArrayList`, I would keep checking in this direction, because the crash report is pretty much saying this, that somehow the `add` ended in the `AbstractList.add` implementation of `add`, and that's dead end (and `ArrayList` shouldn't land there never ever).

Comment: BTW, aren't you doing the Arrays.asList(...) thing, or how it is precisely spelled? Result of such conversion is NOT `ArrayList`, but actually one of those crippled ones, where `add` fails, as underlying classic array is fixed size in Java.